# Connect iOS Device to Some other Device like Android phone for file transfer using bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bluetooth

I have a requirement of searching the available bluetooth devices and get paired with them for file transfer using my App. Although I knew that Apple doesn't support the feature of connecting iOS device to other devices using Bluetooth. The default frameworks like CoreBluetooth, GameKit, etc doesn't allow such features. So my questions are:-

1. Is there any private API that allow to search , pair and connect to devices other than iOS
   devices?
2. If I use any private API , will my App be approved at the time of Submission to App Store?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `CoreBluetooth.framework` is for Bluetooth Low-Energy, not for classical Bluetooth... Since not a lot of Android have a framework for Bluetooth Low Energy, you can forget about it. iDevice support these kinds of profiles: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: If you use any private API's your app will __rejected__ by apple.

Comment: +1 i always wanted to know that. :)